# how to obtain a plane projection of a `StreamPlot3D`

Tags: projection, plotting

StreamPlot3D are rather difficult to decipher.  Is there a simple way to obtain the projection of such a plot onto  a given plane?  Ideally, I am looking for a method which does not even create the StreamPlot3D, since I am  still in the process of getting the version 12.3 where this command appeared.

Comment: This sort of thing?: `StreamPlot3D[{y^2, 1, x}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}] /. {Graphics3D -> Graphics, {x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {x - z, y + z}}`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Is there a function`StreamPlot3D`in newer Mathematica version?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, [`StreamPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot3D.html) is in V12.3.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @MichaelE2's comment:

As far as I know there exists only `VectorPlot3D` in Mathematica v12.1

First one has to define the normal `n` of the plane

```
n={1,1,1}
```

The projection of an arbitrary vector `v` into this plane follows to `v-v.n/n.n n`

Now we still have to define a coordinate system `e1,e2` inside the plane, examplary

```
e1 = (# - # . n/n . n n) &[{1, 0, 0}];
e2 = (# - # . n/n . n n) &[{0, 1, 0}];

pic=VectorPlot3D[{y^2, 1, x}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1,1}, {z, -1, 1}] /.   Arrow[Tube[{a_, b_}, c_]] :> Arrow[{a, b}] (*eliminate Tube*) 
pic /. {Graphics3D ->Graphics, 
{x_Real, y_Real,z_Real} :> {# . e1, # . e2} &[{x, y,z} - {x, y, z} . n/n . n n]}
```

[image]

Comment: @chris Thanks for your hint, now the code should run...

Comment: You might want to keep the connectivity like this? `Cases[pic /. {{x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {# . e1, # . e2} &[{x, y, 
       z} - {x, y, z} . n/n . n n]}, Line[a__, b_] -> Line[a], 
  Infinity] // Graphics`

Comment: Without `//Graphics` Mathematica returns `{}` ?

Comment: oops :this works if pic= StreamPlot3D[....

Comment: @chris Is `StreamPlot3D`  a new function in Mathematica version>12.1?

Comment: yes cf https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot3D.html  so you are right I am not addressing the request of the OP